# How can I tell what nodes are highlighted on a displayed JTree?

Tags: java, jtree

I'm working on an app that displays a JTree. I want the user to be able to highlight certain nodes and then do things to those nodes after they press a button.

Highlighting already works - they can click on things, and then shift-click or control click to highlight other things. is there any way to detect which nodes are highlighted in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by *things* and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to find all the tree nodes that a user has selected. See `JTree.getSelectionPaths()`. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getSelectionPaths%28%29) states that it returns

> An array of TreePath objects indicating the selected nodes, or null if nothing is currently selected

Each [TreePath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html)

> represents an array of objects that uniquely identify the path to a node in a tree. The elements of the array are ordered with the root as the first element of the array

As @MadProgrammer states in the comment the last object in the array is the selected node.

Comment: FYI: The last "component" in the path is the actually selected "node", but the approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TreeSelectionListener as follows and use `e.paths` from the `TreeSelectionEvent`:

```
jTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        // e.paths has the selected nodes in the TreeModel
    }
});
```